# Sublime Text 3 [ctrl+comma] on Mac

Tags: html, windows, macos, sublimetext3, key-bindings

On my windows machine, pressing `[crtl+comma]` when in an HTML or CSS tag selects the entire tag and it's contents. I am not sure what this key binding command is called and could not find it in the default Windows sublime-keymap file.

How can I do this on Mac? I know there is the expand selection to tag key binding which is `[ctrl+shift+a]`(windows)/`[cmd+shift+a]`(mac), but it's not exactly the same behavior and doesn't work on css.

Comment: most likely it is a plugin that sets this keybinding, as it is not part of the default keymap. Do you have a plugin installed on your Windows instance of Sublime Text that isn't on your Mac instance of Sublime Text?

Comment: Both use emmet. Maybe there is a keybinding that is different in that plugin on mac/windows. I'll look into that now

Comment: from https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet it says: `Match Tag Pair Outward – ⌃D (Mac) / Ctrl+, (PC)`

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <kbd>ctrl+,</kbd> functionality you describe on Windows is called `Match Tag Pair Outward`, and is provided by [a plugin called Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet). On a Mac, the default keyboard shortcut for the same command is <kbd>⌃D</kbd>.